# Desafío con la alineación vertical de elementos en HTML

Tags: html

Recientemente, completé un curso introductorio de HTML y CSS, y aunque estoy emocionado de aplicar lo que aprendí, me encuentro con un desafío específico relacionado con la alineación vertical de elementos en mi página web.Estoy intentando alinear verticalmente un elemento dentro de un contenedor, pero no estoy obteniendo los resultados deseados. He probado varias soluciones, incluyendo flexbox y alineaciones absolutas, pero aún no encuentro la solución adecuada.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Mi Página Web</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="contenedor">
    <div class="elemento-a-alinear">`introducir el código aquí`
        <!-- Contenido del elemento -->
        <p>Contenido aquí</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sin saber que resultado quieres obtener es dificil